# OpenCL dlopen issue

Tags: android, opencl, dlopen

I'm trying to dlopen /system/vendor/lib/libOpenCL.so on a samsung running Android 7.0, and I'm getting an error I haven't encountered before:

E/linker: library "/system/vendor/lib/libOpenCL.so" ("/system/vendor/lib/libOpenCL.so") needed or dlopened by "/data/app/.../lib/arm64/libCLProcessor.so" is not accessible for the namespace: [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="..."])

It works on another android 7.0 device (Motorola G4) with the libOpenCL.so in the same directory.

Anyone have any idea why it works on one device and not the other?

I'm using the code from https://github.com/krrishnarraj/libopencl-stub/blob/master/src/libopencl.c to dlopen/use the cl functions, and they my cl kernels work great on the device that actually opens the open cl library.

Comment: Also, both devices have libOpenCL.so listed in their /vendor/etc/public.libraries.txt files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a Inforce build problem as /libOpenCL.so is not populated into `/system/etc/public.libraries.txt`.

I was able to fix the same problem on a Inforce Developing board by editing the file (added `libOpenCL.so`).

Answer (score 1):

On newer android versions the fix for me was to add **libOpenCL.so** to:

`/vendor/etc/public.libraries.txt`

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234905/how-to-modify-vendor-etc-public-libraries-txt-when-building-pure-aosp) for reference

**NOTE**:
Adding it to `/system/etc/public.libraries.txt` as others have suggested prevented the device from booting

Answer (score 0):

Android limit the private library access, App developer can't access the library. [Google Document](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/improving-stability-with-private-cc.html)

And if you are app developer (I mean can't access system file).Just have two solution:

1. use the public NDK APIs
2. to include its own copy of those libraries.

In this case OpenCL, copy the library to your app, or use another API

Answer (score 0):

check if `libOpenCL.so` exists in `/system/etc/public.libraries.txt`

if not, add `libOpenCL.so` into the file above, then you may reboot your device to make changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If your device already have `libOpenCL.so` listed in `public.libraries.txt`, then check your Android Manifest file to make sure the following code exist

```
<application
  ...>

  <uses-native-library
    android:name="libOpenCL.so"
    android:required="false"/>

  <uses-native-library
    android:name="libOpenCL-pixel.so"
    android:required="false" />

</application>
```