# How to modify "vendor/etc/public.libraries.txt" when building pure AOSP

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android-source

**ENV**: pure `AOSP (android-9.0.0_r20)` for `marlin target (PIXEL XL)`

I want to add my own library `libOwnlibrary.so` to the `vendor/etc/public.libraries.txt` whitelist file so that I can load it from my own `system/priv-app/MyOwnApp.apk` APK

Currently I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libOwnlibrary.so" needed or dlopened by "/system/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
```

Which makes sense due to the limitations introduced with Android 7.0 (API 24):
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#ndk

> Starting in Android 7.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically
>   linking against non-NDK libraries, which may cause your app to crash.

My current setup:

````
AOSP-root-folder/
    - vendor/
        - myvendor/
            device-partial.mk (this basically instructs `make` to copy libOwnlibrary.so to vendor/lib/libOwnlibrary.so
                    ```PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := .. .so```
            proprietary/
                Android.mk (pushes presigned prebuilt MyOwnApp.apk to /system/priv-app)
                    ```... include$(BUILD_PREBUILT)```
````

What should I change / add in order to be able to modify the `vendor/etc/public.libaries.txt` whitelist file to add `libOwnlibrary.so` to it.

!!! **One way that could work** would be to add `libOwnlibrary.so` to

`AOSP-root-folder/system/core/rootdir/etc/public.libraries.android.txt`

that translates into `system/etc/public.libraries.txt` on the device,

**BUT** that would mean moving my lib to `system/lib` from `vendor/lib` and **I don't think that's allowed.** !!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a step in device-partial.mk to append your lib name to the existing file `vendor/etc/public.libaries.txt`

after this step

````
device-partial.mk (this basically instructs `make` to copy libOwnlibrary.so to vendor/lib/libOwnlibrary.so
                    ```PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := .. .so```
````